# How to use order by inside select statement in c# linq with if else condition

Tags: c#, linq

```
select new 
{      
  DueDate = dd.DueDate, 
  DateType = dd.DateType,
  Quantity = dd.Quantity,
}
```

I need to order by the above due date by the condition

Condition : If its ascending - due date should be ordered by asc
else descending
Due date will differ from each Record

Need to check condition while querying

Comment: Its completely unclear what you´re trying to do. Do you want to order if a conditions is met? Or what should the check do? Anyway show what you´ve tried so far.

Comment: Are you looking for `OrderBy`? `select(dd => new {DueDate = dd.DueDate,...}).OrderBy(item => item.DueDate)`

Comment: Yes you are right. Need to order depending upon the condition

Comment: And what should happen when the condition does *not* pass?

Comment: It should order by descending

Comment: Im having a condition variable, it has asc/des
if it asc need to order that due date by asc and vice versa

Comment: Put the condition inside the `where` clause. Put some effort into clarifying your question.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like this should do it:

```
bool myCondition = // false/true;
var myList = myInput.Select new 
{      
    DueDate = dd.DueDate, 
    DateType = dd.DateType,
    Quantity = dd.Quantity,
};

var result = (myCondition  ? 
        myList.OrderBy(x => x.DueDate) : 
        myList.OrderByDescending(x => x.DueDate)
    ).Select(x => new { DueDate = x.DueDate });
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, I have tried this. Here we are ordering after query.. i need to order by while querying itself

Comment: Show your query. It´s quite unclear how you do your actual query.

Comment: select new DemandLine
                          { DueDate = dd.DueDate,
                              ObjSubParentProductFamily = new SubParentProductFamily { SubParentProductFamilyId = v.SubParentProductFamilyId },
                              UnitPrice = Convert.ToDecimal(14.50),
} 

here i need to order by due date depending upon condition

Comment: Please put it into your question so that everyone can see it. Come on, share your affords, we´re not here to guess what you might want to achieve .

Comment: I´ve edited my answer according your question-edit. Notice that as linq is executed deferedly the query is executed just once, although the order-statement is not in the same line.

Comment: your edit does not contain what you put in the comment. I still can't see what it is you are trying to affect the order of.

Comment: The order is built *into* the query, not *after*. However your query is not executed when you call `Select`. This happens when calling `MoveNext()` on `IEnumerator` which is done implicitely for example when iterating your elemnts in a `foreach`-loop or when calling `ToList`.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are looking for is something like:

```
items.Select (item => new 
                         { 
                           x = item.y == cond ? item.y : Sort(item.y);
                           // if item.y == condition, then item.y ELSE Sort item.y
                           ...
                         }
              );
```

Date has to be declared outside the `new {...}`block of course. However, if the date changes for each item, then I would suggest using a simple for loop to do the job.